# Parse (1.3.0.1) forces include of Facebook sdk, but conflicts with libPods.a

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I updated to Parse (1.3.0.1), and it would not compile, as there was an include that erring on this line in PFFacebookUtils.h:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

I installed the Facebook SDK and then added the FacebookSDK framework, and I was able to compile the app.  However the app does not link because of a duplicate symbol.  Here's the error dump:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kevinw/Documents/IOS/JSwipe/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appStoreId in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTaskCompletionSource._task in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._includeStatusBarInSize in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._labelView in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._closeButton in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._insideTapGestureRecognizer in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._closed in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._textColor in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._refererAppLink in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._delegate in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._viewToMoveWithNavController in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._attachedToNavController in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._view in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._lastShownUrl in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._lastShownBFUrl in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._delegate in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._didFinishLoad in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._didFailLoadWithError in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._hasLoaded in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolver in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolver in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._result in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._error in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._exception in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._cancelled in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._completed in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._lock in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._condition in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._callbacks in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFTask in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFTask.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _kBFMultipleErrorsError in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Bolts.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Bolts in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Bolts.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Bolts in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Bolts.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._sourceURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._targets in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._webURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._isBackToReferrer in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkDataParameterName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkTargetKeyName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkUserAgentKeyName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkExtrasKeyName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererAppLink in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererAppName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererUrl in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkVersionKeyName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkVersion in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLink in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLink in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFExecutor._block in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFExecutor in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._inputURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._targetURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._inputQueryParameters in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._targetQueryParameters in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkData in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkExtras in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkReferer in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFURL in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFURL.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._extras in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._appLinkData in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._appLink in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkNavigation in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkNavigation in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _warnOnMissingEventName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFMeasurementEvent._name in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFMeasurementEvent._args in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFMeasurementEventNotificationName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFMeasurementEventNameKey in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFMeasurementEventArgsKey in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkParseEventName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateInEventName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateOutEventName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkNavigateBackToReferrerEventName in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /Users/kevinw/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/kevinw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JSwipe-ctqmquxfahqdyufengcbtphxyoar/Build
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now we are on Parse 1.4.0...yay.

Seems like the pod update is not working.

I ended up linking in the 1.4.0 frameworks from https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing:

```
Parse.framework
ParseFacebookUtils.framework
```

I had to the Bolts.framework due to conflicts, and installed the FacebookSDK via developers.facebook.com.

Then I made sure these frameworks were installed:

```
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

and another Parse forgot to mention in their docs:

```
Social.framework
```

Things are now running with the latest Parse 1.4.0

Comment: Missing Social.framework was creating issue for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Temporary fix is to just revert to 1.3.0 in pods

```
pod 'Parse', '1.3.0'
```

Then go back to 1.3.0.1 when a real solution is found

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me today:

```
workspace 'MyKickButtApp'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'EstimoteSDK'
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.4'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.4'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.19'
```

Comment: worked for me too - make sure you delete the references to Parse, parseFacebookUtils or Facebook-iOS-SDk that you imported previously.